# how to row wise manipulate the data from a "show databases" query result set

Tags: mysql, database

Suppose I have a database data1 which gives me this:

show tables;

---

table1

table2

table3

---

Now instead of individually executing "select * from each table" i want to create a procedure which goes through each database shown in "show databases;" resultset, and then executes select * from each table of that database. I thought of using cursors which would scroll down the resultset, hold each database name in a variable and then execute select statement on each table of that database traversing in the same way. Can someone kindly help me out with how to use cursors in this case, as i am only aware of using cursors for SELECT and UPDATE statements.

btw i use MYSQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll refrain from asking why you would do this. Here is a general strategy in pseudocode;

[words in parentheses are (SQL commands and tables) which will run on your mySQL server.]

Connect to your mySQL server with your favourite tool/programming language and:

```
-- (USE information_schema;)

for db in (select distinct table_schema from tables;)
do:    
    for table in (select table_name from tables where table_schema='$db';)
    do:
        select field,column,attribute from $table;
    done
done
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

you can get the query from infromation_Schema instead of 'show datbases'

Comment: i didnt get you jess. Information_Schema itself is a database which holds system information regarding the mysql dbms.It also holds a "Tables" table which has table names,table column types and their names.My concern is to pull out only the table names one by one and run SELECT query on them.How do i do that?

Comment: now that you can do it with a select statement instead of show, you can use the cursor